# unable to reload data in viewpager

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have implemented a viewpager with tableview. The problem is that initially it loads correct data for Sunday(case 0). Then, I click on Monday(case 1), it does not do inside the below  method.Clicking on  Tuesday loads right data,but clicking on Wednesday again does not go inside the below method. Same thing continues again, if I am on Wednesday, thursday data does not load but clicking on friday loads friday's data.

Here's the   code :

```
- (UIViewController *)viewPager:(ViewPagerController *)viewPager contentViewControllerForTabAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
UIViewController *cvc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];    
switch (index){

    case 0:
          [sunday reloadData];            
          break;
    case 1:
        [monday reloadData];           
        break;
    case 2:
        [tuesday reloadData];
        break;
    case 3:
        [wednesday reloadData];
        break;
    case 4:
        [thursday reloadData];
        break;
    case 5:
        [friday reloadData];
        break;
    case 6:
       [saturday reloadData];
        break;
  }
  return cvc;
}
```

Comment: The code you've included likely works just fine. You should look to see if `index` is the number you expect it to be when you click on Wednesday.

Comment: i am unable to get the value of index, as clicking on wednesday does not go inside this method.

Comment: So it sounds like the problem you are having is not in the code that you listed above.  It's a problem somewhere else.  If you can't figure it out, can you edit your question to show what code runs when you click on Tuesday and what code *should* be running when you click on Wednesday?  I.E. not the `contentViewControllerForTabAtIndex`, but what runs when Tuesday is clicked?

Comment: that's the problem, clicking on Tuesday goes to case 2 of above code...but Wednesday doesn't go anywhere neither in above code nor in any other method of the viewpager.